# Dynamically add directive attribute to an element through another directive and make the first 'active'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I will try to be more specific. I'm using [tooltip](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tooltip) directive of [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) suite. It permit me to bind a tooltip to an input `tag`, in this way:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    ng-model="inputModel" class="form-control"
    placeholder="tooltip without directive"
    tooltip="blabla"
    tooltip-placement="top"
    tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
    tooltip-enable="!inputModel" />
```

For a series of reasons I would dinamically attach the `tooltip="blabla"` property to the DOM element. So i've created a directive to do the job:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .directive('errorHandler', Directive)

    function Directive(){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link : function(s,e,a) {
          e.attr('tooltip', 'blabla');
        }
      };
    }
})();
```

So when I write:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    error-handler
    ng-model="inputModel" class="form-control"
    placeholder="tooltip with directive"
    tooltip-invalid-required="obbligatorio"
    tooltip-placement="top"
    tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
    tooltip-enable="!inputModel" />
```

The resulting code is equal to the code of the first snippet, but the tooltip doesn't appear. Why I've tried with `compile` but something I've missed. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVBZ7ejWTespWP5WU0a3?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out the dynamic Tooltip document for AngularJs+Bootstrap [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip).
Hope it helps you.